# Create a character from column names (in R)

Tags: r, regex, character

I have a matrix with thousands of columns which names are as shown below:

```
Z41_5_tes_ACGTTCCATAGCCGTA
Z41_5_ACGTTCCAGAGCGGTA
Z53_5_ACGTTCCAGAGCCGTA
Z53_5_ACGTTCCAGATCTGTA
Z41_5_ACGTTGCATAGCGGTA
Z41_5_tes_ACGTTCGCTAGCCGTA
```

I would like to create a vector with names that include the beginning of each columns names as shown below:

```
Z41_5_tes
Z41_5
Z53_5
Z53_5
Z41_5
Z41_5_tes
```

I have tried but here I did not capture Z41_5_tes.
names <- gsub("^([^*]**[^_]*).*$", "\1", colnames(x@data))

```
Z41_5
Z53_5
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Remove everything after the last underscore.

```
sub('_[^_]*$', '', x)
#[1] "Z41_5_tes" "Z41_5"     "Z53_5"     "Z53_5"     "Z41_5"     "Z41_5_tes"
```

2. Extract everything before last underscore.

```
sub('(.*)_.*', '\\1', x)
#[1] "Z41_5_tes" "Z41_5"     "Z53_5"     "Z53_5"     "Z41_5"     "Z41_5_tes"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("Z41_5_tes_ACGTTCCATAGCCGTA", "Z41_5_ACGTTCCAGAGCGGTA", 
       "Z53_5_ACGTTCCAGAGCCGTA", "Z53_5_ACGTTCCAGATCTGTA", 
       "Z41_5_ACGTTGCATAGCGGTA", "Z41_5_tes_ACGTTCGCTAGCCGTA")
```